# Spring Data Jpa OneToMany save bidirectional

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with saving child entities.

Here is my example. My model classes look like this:

```
@Entity
public class ImportDocument {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String title;

    private boolean imported;

    @Transient
    private Status status;

    @Basic
    private char statusValue;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "importDocument" , cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<ImportDocumentItem> importDocumentItems;
}


@Entity
public class ImportDocumentItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "import_document_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private ImportDocument importDocument;
}
```

I have implemented JpaRepository interfaces for both domain classes.
I try to save with:

```
importDocumentRepository.save(importDocument);
```

When I save `ImportDocument` object, everything is inserted. But the problem is that, the `import_document_item.import_document_id` (which is foreign key of import_document_id) attribute is filled with null value, not with id of import_document that I expected. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set entity relations on both side before saving. Here an example

```
ImportDocument importDocument = new ImportDocument();
//...
importDocument.setImportDocumentItems(items);
items.forEach(ImportDocumentItem::setImportDocument);

importDocumentRepository.save(importDocument);
```

Comment: hello, how to avoid cyclic?

Comment: Just save the parent, or owning, entity, that should save the child, or owned, entity