# Foreign-key in tb_child is null with bidirectional one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I´m creating my first Spring Boot application with the Java Persistence API to write to and read from a postgres database. I´ve looked through many tutorials and posts to figure out my exact problem and it seems like I currently have a bidirectional one-to-many relationship with two entities (`Parent` and `Child`), but the foreign-key of the `child` column is always `null` when I write to the database.

**ParentEntity:**

```java
@Entity
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tb_parent")
public class Parent {
    @Schema(description = "id of the parent")
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Schema(description = "child-list of the application")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children;
}
```

**ChildEntity:**

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tb_child")
public class Child{
    @Schema(description = "id of the child")
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

**ParentService:**

```java
...
    @Override
    public Parent create(Parent parent) {
        log.info("save new parent: {}", parent);
        return parentRepo.save(parent);   // the repo is an interface that extends the JpaRepository
    }
...
```

After invoking the `create` method, I have a `parent` row in the `tb_parent` with a generated `id` and one or more `child` rows in the `tb_child` with a generated `id` and a `null` value for the `parent_id` column.

Even though I´m able to find lots of posts describing a similar issue, I wasn´t yet able to find a solution that works for me.

**Update #1:**

A common suggestion is to manually set the `parent` object in all `child` elements. However, this results in a Stackoverflow Exception due to the circular structure.

```java
    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        children.forEach(child -> child.setParent(this));
        this.children = children;
    }
```

Additionally, it kinda feels off because almost everything is managed automatically by the JPA Annotations and then you have to manually sync the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data Jpa OneToMany save bidirectional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722440/spring-data-jpa-onetomany-save-bidirectional)

Comment: @GeorgyLvov I´ve already a similar approach to also store the parent on all child elements, however, this results in a Stackoverflow Exception because of the circular structure. See update #1.

Comment: `StackoverflowError` is due to `@Data` annotation on your entities, here is a useful [link](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Georgy Lvov** I was able to find the most effective solution. I had to do the following steps:

1. remove the `@Data` annotation as suggested by **Georgy Lvov** (Thank you so much!) This basically avoids the generated getter and setter methods for all attributes and the methods equals(), hashCode(), and toString() by Lombok which caused the Stackoverflow Exception.
2. annotate the `Set<Child> children;` variable in the `Parent` class with the `@JsonManagedReference` annotation. see below:

```java
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Schema(description = "child-list of the application")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children;
```

3. annotate the `private Parent parent;` in the `Child` class with the `@JsonBackReference` annotation. see below:

```java
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private Parent parent;
```

The `@JsonBackReference` also seems to avoid the circular structure when you create an `openapi.json` file.

Comment: stil have cyclic :/